# Insert htp.p printed value into a table

Tags: oracle, variables, oracle-apex

I have two regions in an *Apex* page. One contains a *PL/SQL* block which print a value like timestamp using `htp.p`  I want to use that value for the other region which is a form for inserting in a table.

```
tsEndTime := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

Htp.p('<h4>' || 'Timp inceput interogare' || tsStartTime|| '</h4>');
```

Answer (score 0):

So insert `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` directly ... what's the point in displaying it on the screen and then inserting that *displayed* value?

Comment: It is one parameters, i need to show it and save in table rezults along with other data.

Comment: OK, so that would be something like  `insert into your_table (id, time_stamp, name) values (:P1_ID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, :P1_NAME)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code according to your need:

```
CREATE TABLE WEB_OUTPUT(MY_OUTPUT VARCHAR2(4000));


DECLARE
    LV_A_THEPAGE     SYS.HTP.HTBUF_ARR;
    LV_I_IROWS       INTEGER;
    LV_I_VERSION     INTEGER;
    LV_A_NAME_ARR    OWA.VC_ARR;
    LV_A_VALUE_ARR   OWA.VC_ARR;
    LV_I_NUM         PLS_INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    LV_I_VERSION := OWA.INITIALIZE;
    OWA.INIT_CGI_ENV(LV_I_NUM, LV_A_NAME_ARR, LV_A_VALUE_ARR);
    HTP.P('<h4>' || 'Timp inceput interogare' || SYSDATE /*tsStartTime*/|| '</h4>'); -- or call to a procedure that will generated HTP like calls
    LV_I_IROWS := 99999999999;
    OWA.GET_PAGE(THEPAGE => LV_A_THEPAGE, IROWS => LV_I_IROWS);
    FOR I IN 1..LV_I_IROWS LOOP
        INSERT INTO WEB_OUTPUT VALUES (LV_A_THEPAGE(I));
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LV_A_THEPAGE(I));
    END LOOP;

END;
/

SELECT * FROM WEB_OUTPUT;
```

Output:

[image]

[DB Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f2ac5e3b29028cc65de41b2c64b0cf75)

Cheers!!